# AutoGrow in SD Grids

Tags: android, genexus

I am working on an Android App (using Genexus). I need to present data from 3 SDTs in my SDPanel (WebServices), so I created 3 grids for that.

The client does not want each grid with its own scrolling - the entire panel must be scroll-able, not the grids individually. This is a requirement.

So i tried to set the "auto grow" property of the grids to true.
However this creates another problem, as this property requires the grid's content not to grow. We are presenting text fields that vary a lot in length and must not be trimmed...

Is there any solution or recommendation for this?
Thanks

Comment: Also, I tried to join the 3 SDTs in one massive grid, loaded in the Load event (each SDT representing a table in the grid which could be visible or invisible), but this created problems as the scrolling seems to mess with the rows height.

Comment: Did you try using one grid with multiple rows layout per each SDT item type: http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Multiple+Layouts+per+Row,